# Compare two strings and highlight mismatch characters in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
string1 = "AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD"
string2 = "AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD"
```

output. Where the mismatch (in this case E) will be replaced with HTML tags around E that color it.

```
A**E**ABBBBBCC**E**CCDDDDD
```

What I tried so far: XOR, diff and substr. First I need to find the indices then replace those indices with the pattern.

Comment: is the size of the two strings always same?

Comment: They are not but I am comparing the substring of string2 that is the same size of string1. basically assume they are.

Comment: The output is the second string highlighting the differences

Comment: What, no [Algorithm::Diff](http://p3rl.org/Algorithm::Diff) answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string1 = 'AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD';
my $string2 = 'AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD';
my $result = '';
for(0 .. length($string1)) {
    my $char = substr($string2, $_, 1);
    if($char ne substr($string1, $_, 1)) {
        $result .= "**$char**";
    } else {
        $result .= $char;
    }
}
print $result;
```

It prints `A**E**ABBBBBCC**E**CCDDDDD` and was tested somewhat, but it may contain errors.

Comment: There are other ways of doing this if you need very high performance (i.e. the strings are very long).

Comment: strings aren't long but there are many strings. i.e. many comparisons

Comment: Try this for a start and post a new question if you run into performance issues. Will each string be compared to other strings many times or just once?

Comment: I ended up using this one. I like the answer with the join but this was easier to read, although I'd like to avoid using substr

Comment: The thing is that ``substr`` is supposed to be very fast in perl. I did consider splitting the strings but decided against it.

Comment: You should iterate over string2, as the OP states the output has to be string2 with differences highlighted (in your case, you output as many chars as string1 ... string2 could be longer)

Comment: I have re-read the question and can't tell what the OP wants, but anyway, I think that the solution provided by @FMc is the best and it does use the second string as comparison base.

Answer (score 8):

```
my @x = split '', "AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD";
my @y = split '', "AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD";

my $result = join '',
             map { $x[$_] eq $y[$_] ? $y[$_] : "**$y[$_]**" }
             0 .. $#y;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my ($s1, $s2, $o1, $o2) = ("AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD", "AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD");
my @s1 = split(//, $s1);
my @s2 = split(//, $s2);
my $eq_state = 1;
while (@s1 and @s2) {
    if (($s1[0] eq $s2[0]) != $eq_state) {
        $o1 .= (!$eq_state) ? "</b>" : "<b>";
        $o2 .= (!$eq_state) ? "</b>" : "<b>";
    }
    $eq_state = $s1[0] eq $s2[0];
    $o1.=shift @s1;
    $o2.=shift @s2;
}
print "$o1\n$o2\n";
```

**Output**

```
A<b>A</b>ABBBBBCC<b>C</b>CCDDDDD
A<b>E</b>ABBBBBCC<b>E</b>CCDDDDD
```

A simpler one that only prints out the second string:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my ($s1, $s2, $was_eq) = ("AAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD", "AEABBBBBCCECCDDDDD", 1); 
my @s1 = split(//, $s1);
my @s2 = split(//, $s2);
for my $idx (0 .. @s2 -1) {
    my $is_eq = $s1[$idx] eq $s2[$idx];
    print $is_eq ? "</b>" : "<b>" if ( $was_eq != $is_eq);
    $was_eq = $is_eq;
    print $s2[$idx];
}
```

**Outout**

```
</b>A<b>E</b>ABBBBBCC<b>E</b>CCDDDDD
```

Comment: +1 for actually iterating over string2 and not string1

Answer (score 3):

This might be memory intensive, for large strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "aabbcc";
my $b = "aabdcc";

my @a = split //, $a;
my @b = split //, $b;

my $new_b = '';

for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@a); $i++) {
    $new_b .= $a[$i] eq $b[$i] ? $b[$i] : "**$b[$i]**";
}
```

#### Output

```
$ test.pl
new_b: aab**d**cc
```

Comment: You should iterate over string2, as the OP states the output has to be string2 with differences highlighted (in your case, you output as many chars as string1 ... string2 could be longer)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this. Below is a possible way to solve this.

```
my $str1="ABCDEA";
my $str2="AECDEB";
my @old1=split("",$str1);
my @old2=split("",$str2);

my @new;

for my $i (0..$#old1) {
        if ($old1[$i] eq $old2[$i] ) {
                push (@new, $old2[$i]);
        }
        else
        {
                my $elem = "**".$old2[$i]."**";
                push (@new , $elem);
        }
}
print @new;
```

The output is:

```
A**E**CDE**B**
```

Comment: You should iterate over string2, as the OP states the output has to be string2 with differences highlighted (in your case, you output as many chars as string1 ... string2 could be longer)

Answer (score 2):

Aligning columns and using the bitwise string operator, "^":

```
my $a = "aabbccP";
my $b = "aabdccEE";
$_ = $a ^ $b;
s/./ord $& ? "^" : " "/ge;
print "$_\n" for $a, $b, $_;
```

gives:

```
aabbccP
aabdccEE
   ^  ^^
```